# difference in result of count and getSize()

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, collection

I am preparing the product collection as follows

```
$visibleProducts = $this->catalogProductVisibility->getVisibleInCatalogIds();
$collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();
$collection->addAttributeToFilter(
    'status',
    ['in' => $this->productStatus->getVisibleStatusIds()]
);
$collection->setVisibility($visibleProducts);
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('sku', ['in' => $skus]);
$collection->addStoreFilter();

$collection->addAttributeToSelect(['new', 'name'])
            ->addAttributeToFilter('new', 1)
            ->setPageSize($limit);
```

`$collection->getSize()` and `count($collection->getItems())` is showing different numbers.

Why is this so?

Comment: which one is wrong `$collection->getSize()` or `count($collection->getItems())` ?

Answer (score 1):

**$collection->getSize()** - getsize return all the products count, it ignores pagination

**count($collection->getItems())** - will show you the count on current page

Answer (score 1):

```
$collection->getSize()
```

this will return all the products count, it ignores pagination

whereas

```
count($collection->getItems())
```

this will show you the count on current page

Comment: What if I don't have pagination?

Comment: remove `->setPageSize($limit);` from collection, and both will show same result